# Load first files in two folders and join them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have two different folder / directories :

```
C:/PartA/...
C:/PartB/...
```

There are files in a well-sorted order, that means the first file in PartA, fits to the file in PartB, how can I loop over the folders and always concat the matching files.

Example (with files in the folders):

```
PartA       PartB
Test1       Outcome0
Test2       Outcome1
```

I want to concat:

```
file1 = pd.concat(['Test1', 'Outcome0'], axis=1)
file2 = pd.concat(['Test2', 'outcome1'], axis=1)
```

Any idea to loop over it?

Comment: Just use `zip` with sorted files in each folder.

Comment: Beware: the order when reading a directory is not guaranteed... What you see with a `dir` or `ls` may not have same order as what a Python script will receive.

Comment: With regard to the file order, and as the earlier comments pointed out, using `sorted` on the list of files returned by `os.listdir` or `glob.glob` might be a good idea. Both documentations say that results are returned in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Python does not receive the order of a windows folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create lists with the file names using:

```
import os, glob
f1_files = glob.glob(first_folder + os.sep + "*.*")
f2_files = glob.glob(second_folder + os.sep + "*.*")
```

Then use a simple loop:

```
all_files = []
for i in range(len(f1_files)):
    all_files.append(pd.concat([f1_files[i], f2_files[i]], axis=1))
```

And after the loop, in `all_files` should be a list with all the concatinated dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
import os

result = [pd.concat([f1, f2], axis=1) for f1, f2 in zip(os.listdir('C:/PartA/'), os.listdir('C:/PartB/'))]
```